# Search ranking in LINQ, MVC 3 and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Previously in SQL I would use something like this to rank my search results:

```
        --search product name
    SELECT tblProduct.ProductID, 20 AS Ranking
    FROM tblProduct
    INNER JOIN tblManufacturer ON tblProduct.ManufacturerID=tblManufacturer.ManufacturerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblProductCollection ON tblProduct.CollectionID=tblProductCollection.CollectionID
    WHERE tblManufacturer.Name + ISNULL(' ' + tblProductCollection.CollectionName, '') + ' ' + tblProduct.Name LIKE '%' + @term + '%'  AND tblProduct.Active = 1
    UNION ALL

    --search product exact name
    SELECT tblProduct.ProductID, 200 AS Ranking
    FROM tblProduct WHERE Name = '%' + term  AND tblProduct.Active = 1
    UNION ALL
```

This example says if your search term is contained in the name: 20 is the rank, if you match the name exactly: 200 is the rank. Union the tables together, order by Ranking(descending) and hey presto!

I'm trying to do this in LINQ this time round and am unsure how to go about doing it, to be honest I'm unsure my previous example was the best way to do it originally.

So, I have a Product Entity mapped to my database and I've added a property in my partial class called SearchRanking:

```
            var query = from p in db.Products
                    where p.Name.Contains(term)
                    select p;

        var query2 = from p in db.Products
                     where p.Name.ToLower() == term
                     select p;
```

Somehow I need to set the properties like so:

```
            var query = from p in db.Products
                    where p.Name.Contains(term)
                    select p, p.SearchRanking = 20;

        var query2 = from p in db.Products
                     where p.Name.ToLower() == term
                     select p, p.SearchRanking = 200;
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to create a new anonymous type you could do this:

```
 var foundProducts = (from p in products
                                 where p.Name.Contains(term)
                                 select new Product  
                                     {
                                         ProductId = p.ProductId,
                                         Category =  p.Category,
                                         Brand =  p.Brand,
                                         SearchRanking = p.Name.ToLower() == term ? 200 : 20
                                     }).OrderBy(s => s.SearchRanking).Take(20);
```

Comment: Oh I like! I have other fields to search too like Category, Brand and cost and things.
Is foundProducts still a type of Product so I can bind my view to List<Product> ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your product type is - does it have SearchRanking built in?  If so, you could project onto the product type instead, and map all the properties there

Comment: Yes Product.SearchRanking exists. Are you suggesting to use Saj's answer?

Comment: I've updated my response - this will also only take the top 20, so you can build your objects at once.

Comment: What do you mean by 'so you can build your objects at once'?

Comment: Below, you had mentioned that you were grouping, then attaching the products after the fact.  I was wanting to show that you can attach the rank/sort/order/create product all in the same statement :)

Comment: Ah yes, I'm not sure if I'll need to t'was a minor digression. But thank you it's working great :) Hopefully there's not too much of a performance hit @ 3000 products on production server.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this;

```
        var query = (from p in db.Products
                    where p.Name.Contains(term)
                    select p).ToList().ForEach(p => p.SearchRanking = 20);
```

A more efficient way would be to;

```
        var query = (from p in db.Products
                    where p.Name.Contains(term)
                    select new Product
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        //set the other props here
                        SearchRanking = 20
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I'm essentially looping the products again to set the Search Ranking, I would prefer something like: select new { ID = p.ID, SearchRanking = 20 } and then group by and then finally at the end reattach all the products. Any thoughts on this from a efficiency point of view?

Comment: I've edited my answer, the second method would be more efficient and you won't be using anonymous types.